# Vegalite daily line chart wobble

Tags: vega, vega-lite, altair

I've run into an issue with vegalite whereby charts exhibit a 'wobbling line' when the line should be straight, and dates are not equally spaced.

Can anyone verify that this is a bug, or am I making a mistake in my spec?
[image].

I have found that this issue becomes more severe when you increase the number of data points.

To replicate this issue, paste the following spec into the [vega lite editor](http://vega.github.io/vega-editor/?mode=vega-lite):

```
{
  "description": "",
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {
        "date": "2017-01-23",
        "value": 100
      },
      {
        "date": "2017-01-24",
        "value": 200
      },
      {
        "date": "2017-01-25",
        "value": 300
      },
      {
        "date": "2017-01-26",
        "value": 400
      },
      {
        "date": "2017-01-27",
        "value": 500
      },
      {
        "date": "2017-01-28",
        "value": 600
      },
      {
        "date": "2017-01-29",
        "value": 700
      },
      {
        "date": "2017-01-30",
        "value": 800
      },
      {
        "date": "2017-01-31",
        "value": 900
      },
      {
        "date": "2017-02-01",
        "value": 1000
      },
      {
        "date": "2017-02-02",
        "value": 1100
      },
      {
        "date": "2017-02-03",
        "value": 1200
      },
      {
        "date": "2017-02-04",
        "value": 1300
      },
      {
        "date": "2017-02-05",
        "value": 1400
      },
      {
        "date": "2017-02-06",
        "value": 1500
      },
      {
        "date": "2017-02-07",
        "value": 1600
      }
    ]
  },
  "mark": "line",
  "encoding": {
    "x": {
      "field": "date",
      "type": "temporal"
    },
    "y": {
      "field": "value"
    }
  },
  "config": [],
  "embed": {
    "renderer": "canvas",
    "actions": {
      "export": false,
      "source": false,
      "editor": false
    }
  }
}
```

Edit:  Followup - experimenting in Altair, it seems like the date aspect of this is irrelevant.  You get the same problem with both of the following code blocks:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from altair import *

s1 = pd.date_range(start="2017-01-23", end="2020-02-07")
s2  = np.arange(1,len(s1)+1)*100
df = pd.DataFrame({"date":s1, "value":s2})

Chart(df).mark_line(
).encode(
    x='date',
    y='value'
)
```

and

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from altair import *

s1 = np.arange(1,1000,1)
s2  = np.arange(1,len(s1)+1)*100
df = pd.DataFrame({"x":s1, "value":s2})

Chart(df).mark_line(
).encode(
    x='x',
    y='value'
)
```

Conversely the following produced a smooth plot (pandas and matplotlib):

```
%matplotlib inline
df.plot('date', 'value')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The wiggle is caused by an effect of rounding error during the calculation of the pixel coordinates relevant to the data values.

Looking at the `vega` code produced by `vega-lite`, one can see the `"round": true` entries for the defined `scale`s. Changing this to `false` solves the problem on my screen, and making `vega-lite` do that, is also possible by adding:

```
"config": {"scale": {"round" : false}},
```

instead of the

```
"config": [],
```

line in the `vega-lite` spec.

Comment: Thanks very much!  In case anyone's using Altair and sees this, you can pass this to Vega using `Chart(df).configure_scale(
round=False)`

Comment: ...and in the R `vegalite` package you have to manually add it i.e. `vl <- vegalite::vegalite()` etc, and once the `vl` list has been created you can do `vl$x$config$scale$round <- FALSE`

Comment: This looks like a bug, we will fix this in Vega-Lite (I'm a Vega-Lite team member).